# Merging sql rows with same values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've added some data to my database and I just found out that I've got a lot of duplicates, with different key of course, and I want to merge them into a single record.

I'd like to do it within the sql database itself, I don't want to truncate the table and insert the values again, without duplicates, because the script is quite slow.

Here's a sample of my scenario:

Table track:

```
key |   artist  | title
----|-----------|--------
k1  |  artist1  | title1
----|-----------|--------
k2  |  artist1  | title1
----|-----------|--------
k3  |  artist1  | title1
```

Table chart:

```
trackKey | otherKey |  anotherKey  |  value
---------|----------|--------------|---------
k1       |   ok1    |      ak4     |    v1
---------|----------|--------------|---------
k3       |   ok2    |      ak2     |    v2
---------|----------|--------------|---------
k1       |   ok3    |      ak9     |    v2
---------|----------|--------------|---------
k2       |   ok4    |      ak1     |    v6
```

where `chart.trackKey` references `track.key`

The result that I'd like to achieve is:

Table track:

```
key |   artist  | title
----|-----------|--------
k1  |  artist1  | title1
```

Table chart:

```
trackKey | otherKey |  anotherKey  |  value
---------|----------|--------------|---------
k1       |   ok1    |      ak4     |    v1
---------|----------|--------------|---------
k1       |   ok2    |      ak2     |    v2
---------|----------|--------------|---------
k1       |   ok3    |      ak9     |    v2
---------|----------|--------------|---------
k1       |   ok4    |      ak1     |    v6
```

so that each duplicate of the same entry in `track` is merged into one row and the old keys in `chart` are updated with the only one that remained in the `track` table.

Is there any way to do this **in SQL**?

EDIT:

Solution #1 based on @popovitsj's answer

```
UPDATE chart c SET trackUri =
(WITH track_unique AS
(
    SELECT MIN(uri) AS key, artist, title, album. artwork FROM track
    GROUP BY artist, title
)
SELECT tu.key FROM chart c1
INNER JOIN track t ON c1.trackUri = t.key
INNER JOIN track_unique tu ON t.artist = tu.artist AND t.title = tu.title
WHERE c1.trackUri = c.trackUri and c1.countryId = c.countryId and c1.date = c.date);
```

returns

```
#1064 - Syntax error near 
'track_unique AS (
SELECT MIN(uri) AS key, artist, title, album. artwork FR' line 2
```

Solution #2 based on @juergen d's answer

```
update chart
join track t1 on t1.uri = chart.trackUri
left join 
(
   select min(uri) as key
   from track 
   group by artist, title
) tmp_track on tmp_track.key = chart.trackUri
set trackkey = tmp_tbl.key
where chart.trackUri not in 
(
  select min(uri)
  from track
  group by artist, title
  having count(*) > 1
);
```

returns

```
#1064 - Syntax error near
   'key
   from track
   group by artist, title
) tmp_track on tmp_track.key = c' line 5
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong so I'm adding the schema definitions (taken from *phpMyAdmin*)

[image]

Comment: If you have to do this in the first place, it is definitely a code smell. Why are you getting duplicates?

Comment: Because the API that I'm using returns duplicates. Each track may have a different uri, based on the country in which is published. This means that track x has a certain uri for the Italian album while it has a different one for the USA's one, but it's still the same track and, for what I need to do, those are considered duplicates

Comment: This comment explains what's really going on.  It isn't data mismanagement (aka code smell).  It's that you are seeking a projection of the data onto a different space.  "Projection" is one of the fundamental operations on relations, the basis of the entire relational system.  Unfortunately, projection requires time, so your best answer is going to run a while.  If you are the DBA, you might find it worthwhile to materialize the projection in a secondary table, but this carries baggage of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first with clause gets the id's you want to keep, then in the next select query you match those id's to the the chart id.

I edited this answer based on your modification of my original answer. This answer assumes that `chart(countryid,date)` uniquely identies a chart, and that tracks may be merged only if `track(key,artist,title,album)` is equal.

```
UPDATE chart c SET trackUri =
(WITH track_unique AS
(
    SELECT MIN(uri) AS key, artist, title, album, artwork FROM track
    GROUP BY artist, title, album, artwork
)
SELECT tu.key FROM chart c1
INNER JOIN track t ON c1.trackUri = t.key
INNER JOIN track_unique tu
ON t.artist = tu.artist
AND t.title = tu.title
AND t.album = tu.album
AND t.artwork = tu.artwork
WHERE c1.trackUri = c.trackUri
AND c1.countryId = c.countryId
AND c1.date = c.date);
```

To delete the leftover duplicates after doing this update:

```
DELETE FROM track
WHERE uri NOT IN
    (SELECT MIN(uri) AS key, artist, title, album, artwork
     FROM track
     GROUP BY artist, title, album, artwork);
```

Comment: `chart`'s key is formed by `(trackKey, otherKey, anotherKey)` and `track`'s key is an `URI`. Is your code still valid?

Comment: Yeah, sure, that just makes the query a little bit longer.

Comment: I've edited the first comment while you posted yours, please check it up

Comment: I don't see why it would matter if the track's key is a URI. It's still comparable so `MIN()` should work.

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that that would give a syntax error. Try my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the duplicate values are *exact* duplicates, you could use

```
SELECT MIN(key),artist,title FROM track GROUP BY artist,title;
```

to get a duplicate-free version of the data in the `track` table.  You could put this in a temporary table and swap them over, or use your SQL client to download the data and re-import it, or whatever-- for safety's sake I wouldn't try to do it all in a single statement...